# Como quitar los márgenes en el content page de xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

que tal, estoy haciendo una pequeña práctica con xamarin forms, pero me pasa que el el teléfono se ve como si tuviera un margen establecido, añado imagen para que vean:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte naranja debería cubrir toda la pantalla a lo ancho.
Añado el código del XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="*, *">

    <Image Source="Organe_top_shape.png" Aspect="AspectFill" />

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">

        <Image Source="Monkey_face.png" WidthRequest="130" Margin="0, -115, 0, 10"/>

        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10">

            <Label Text="Meal" FontSize="34" FontFamily="Cabin" TextColor="#FC6011"/>
            <Label Text="Monkey" FontSize="34" FontFamily="Cabin" TextColor="#4A4B4D"/>
            
        </StackLayout>

        <Label Text="Food Delivery" FontSize="11" CharacterSpacing="5" WidthRequest="130" FontFamily="Metropolis" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="#4A4B4D"/>
        <Label Text="Discover the best foods from over 1,000 restaurants and fast delivary to your doorset." HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" CharacterSpacing="4" FontFamily="Metropolis" Margin="27, 40, 27, 60" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="#4A4B4D"/>

        <Button Text="Login" WidthRequest="310" HeightRequest="57" CornerRadius="30" HorizontalOptions="Center" Background="#FC6011" TextColor="#fff"/>
        <Button Text="Create an Account" WidthRequest="310" HeightRequest="57" CornerRadius="30" HorizontalOptions="Center" Background="#fff" TextColor="#FC6011" BorderColor="#FC6011" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0"/>

    </StackLayout>

</Grid>
```